# I can't seem to generate content for dynamic content load

Tags: ajax, wordpress

I am using wordpress and php along with ajax to create a random loading of customer reviews on our main page

```js
function loadContent() {
  $.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: 'http://skillsetsonline.ssosv.com/contentLoader.php',
    data: {
      company: 1
    },
    success: function(data) {
      alert(data);
      var currReview = document.getElementById('reviewRand');
      currReview.innerHTML = data;
    }
  });
}
setTimeout(loadContent, 10000); // milliseconds, so 10 seconds = 10000ms
```

```html
<div id="reviewRand" class="elementToFadeInAndOut" style="font-color:#FFF;">Hi how are you</div>
```

I pasted the ajax command in from a stackoverflow posting that was an accepted answer but may not have it exactly right this does not include the fading CSS code I use but that is working I just need to change the content.
Currently "Hi how are you" fades in every 10 seconds. One thing I have not learned about yet with this ajax command is the

data:{company:1}

I know it simply passes &company=1 to the GET URL but in my case I do not need to send anything and since it should not break anything if it is sent I left it alone not sure if

data:{}

would work and be cleaner
I have verified that the url used does get a random review
formatted like this

```
I love this program.blah blah.<br>
A USER<br>
A location<br>
June 2016<br>
```

Each line is formatted in CSS via a class tag

Any ideas would be greatly appreciated

Comment: You do not need to declare the `data` key if there is nothing you are sending over to the server in your AJAX request. Can you include in your question what an example returned data from the AJAX request is? Is it returned as plain text, in a JSON format, or something else?

Comment: If you don't need to pass a query string or any POST info, then just remove the `data: {}` line entirely - it isn't required.

Comment: What's your website URL? Is it on http://skillsetsonline.ssosv.com, too? Do you have any errors in your browser console?

Comment: what's in contentLoader.php? Unless that contains something, I don't see anything to do with Wordpress in your code. Are you avoiding admin-ajax.php for a reason?

Comment: OK I under stand that I can leave off the data field completely and will do

Comment: this is the code that will reside in a wordpress site. its purpose is to display a customer review. This code contains a div tag with an id of reviewRand. It also has CSS code that makes the content of this div tag fade in for 2 seconds remain visible for 6 and then fade out for 2 seconds. The process then uses the ajax to run the contentLoader .php file on the server which will generate a single customer review and return that content and load it into the div tag and the cycle repeats by fading in the new review and then fading it out and then repeating the whole process again.

Comment: The content return is not JSON it is four lines of simple text each created as a its own div tag so I can format it any way I want as it fades in and fades out in the wordpress document

Comment: As I did state the content does work out side of the wordpress site which leads me to believe that wordpress is somehow blocking my normal use of javascript to access and load the innerhtml of the specific div tag I am trying to manipulate which is the has the id of reviewRand

Comment: What exactly is happening? This does seem to work as intended.

Answer (score 7):

Since the domain you're making the AJAX request to is on a different domain/origin, what you're running in to is a CORS issue. By default, the client will not allow you to update the page with data from an AJAX request that is served on a different origin than the site where the request originated. You can read about making CORS changes here https://enable-cors.org/

A common way around this is to serve the response via JSONP. You can do this in your script at `http://skillsetsonline.ssosv.com/contentLoader.php` if you have access to change that file. There are also third-party sites that will request that URL for you and create a proxy that serves the response via JSONP, then you can use it on your website.

Here's an example utilizing a JSONP proxy on https://crossorigin.me

```js
function loadContent() {
  $.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: 'https://crossorigin.me/http://skillsetsonline.ssosv.com/contentLoader.php',
    success: function(data) {
      var currReview = document.getElementById('reviewRand');
      currReview.classList.add('ready');
      currReview.innerHTML = data;
    }
  });
}

setTimeout(loadContent, 0); /* changed this for the demo */
```

```css
#reviewRand:not(.ready) {
    text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="reviewRand"><img src="http://thinkfuture.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/10/loading_spinner.gif"></div>
```

Comment: Well explaind by Michael